# Sending an email with inline picture on App Engine since 1.9.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I am currently trying to send an email with a picture inside the mail using the Google App Engine 1.9.5. This features is availible only from the version 1.9.0 of the SDK :

```
Users now have the ability to embed images in emails via the Content-Id attachment header.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=965
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10503
```

Source : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

This is my code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("leo.mieulet@xxx.com", "xxx.com newsletter"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("leo.mieulet@xx.com", "Leo Mieulet"));
msg.setSubject("Inline image test : "+new Date().getTime());

String imageCid = "graph";
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageBase64, "image/png");
MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
imagePart.setFileName(imageCid + ".png");
imagePart.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
imagePart.addHeader("Content-ID", "<" + imageCid + ">");

String htmlBody = "My html text... <img src=\"cid:"+imageCid+"\"> ... ends here.";
// Create alternate message body.
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent("<html><body>"+htmlBody+"</body></html>", "text/html");

final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);

msg.setContent(multipart);
msg.saveChanges();

Transport.send(msg);
```

I receive an email which looks like :
[image]
Could anyone help me with the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the imageBase64 variable name, you seems to give to the ByteArrayDataSource the image already encoded in Base64. You should directly use the image byte array without Base64.encode() it.

Comment: In gmail, it is coming as attachment and image is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Awesome ! ;)

If you want to display the image in pure HTML ( in app-engine doGet() context ) :

```
//byte[] imgContent =  the content of your image
Base64 base64 = new Base64(); 
imgContent = base64.encode(imgContent);
resp.getWriter().write("<html><img src='data:image/png;base64,"+new String(imgContent)+"'></html>");
```

And as said @benoit-s, you don't need to encode in base64 the content of your image.
I just edited this line :

```
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageBase64, "image/png");
```

to

```
//byte[] imageAsByteArray =  the content of your image
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageAsByteArray, "image/png");
```

Comment: In gmail, it is coming as attachment and image is not displaying

Comment: I just tested and I do not see the picture as attachment and image is  well displayed.
If I look at the source of the mail, I see on the HTML :

     <img src=3D"cid:graph"> 

And the content of the picture at the end of the mail : 


     Content-ID: <graph>
     X-Attachment-Id: a664a0d2085f57e2_0.1
     iVBORw0KGgoAAAO0JN8T.... (the image as binary)